# Using a stopwatch to benchmark application usage

Tags: c#, oop, class, stopwatch

Hi I am trying to make a global class that I can use in my projects, I intend to use this as my default template, I am a newbie so please be patient ;)

```
Stopwatch Masterstopwatch = new Stopwatch();

#if DEBUG

    private static void ApplicationLogStart()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Masterstopwatch.Start();

        String eventName = "Program Loaded";
        String errorDetails = "Program has started Succesfully";
        DataLogEntry(eventName, errorDetails);
    }
    private static void ApplicationLogclosing()
    {
        String eventName = "Program is closing";
        String errorDetails = "Program has closed Succesfully";
        DataLogEntry(eventName, errorDetails);
        StopTime = DateTime.Now;
        Masterstopwatch.Stop();
        Benchmark(StartTime,StopTime,Masterstopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
#endif
```

I suspect that I am fundimently flawed in my design as I want the Stopwatch Masterstopwatch = new Stopwatch(); to be declared globally without using a method, I suspect that this is not posible, but I need to ask
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

If you declare a wrapper around stopwatch as follows you can use it anywhere in your app and access the same instance of a Stopwatch.

```
// Declare singleton wrapper of a stopwatch, which instantiates stopwatch
// on construction
public class StopwatchProxy 
{
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
    private static readonly StopwatchProxy _stopwatchProxy = new StopwatchProxy();

    private StopwatchProxy()
    {
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public Stopwatch Stopwatch { get { return _stopwatch; } } 

    public static StopwatchProxy Instance
    { 
        get { return _stopwatchProxy; }
    }
}

// Use singleton
class Foo
{
    void Foo()
    {
        // Stopwatch instance here
        StopwatchProxy.Instance.Stopwatch.Start();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    void Bar()
    {
        // Is the same instance as here
        StopwatchProxy.Instance.Stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see correct Singleton here. This is not thread safe at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, since the .NET runtime ensures `private static readonly _stopwatchProxy = new StopwatchProxy()` is called only once per AppDomain. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612.aspx for info

Comment: Ha. Didn't know about that. You learn something new every day.

Comment: To be fair I also had to check ;-) Saves double locking and all that shebang. Also handy when asked a pedantic interview question!